# RegEx in php to match disallowed chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a problem with matching "bad" lines. Every string with length outside of 6-8 character range and does contain any characters other than numbers or ":" should be matched. See examples below.

These strings should *not* be marked:

```
001000
000000
236849
576852
09:34:24
23:59:59
00:00:00
```

I only want these three to be marked:

```
123456789
67855jkl
5678lk
```

Code:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?![0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*$|(?![0-9]{0,8})$/', $user->start)) {
    echo "<font color='$ce'>Fehler </font></br>";
} else {
    echo "<font color='$cn'>Kein Fehler </font></br>";
}
```

Comment: explain your question better please

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, there are infinitely many regular expression patterns which can match a given string. Telling us that you just want to last 3 to be marked is not enough. Please provide samples you want to match and others you want to discard.

Comment: I new to stackoverflow, so I don't know how to edit. Samples are shown on the picture. I want everything to be matched which are not in a range of 6-8 chars and contains anything else than numbers or ":"

Comment: `^(?!(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}|\d{6,8}$).+$`

Comment: Hei, seems to work, but I've another question. Is it also possible to define that it can only be 8 chars long if the 3 and the 6 char is a ":" otherwise it's matched so that 12345678 is matched because there is no ":" at the 3rd and 6th postition?

Answer (score 0):

This is your own code with an updated `^(?:.{1-6}|.{9,}|(?=.*[a-z]).*)$` regex ([tested here](https://regex101.com/r/qO4sQ1/1)):

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:.{1-6}|.{9,}|(?=.*[a-z]).*)$/m', $user->start)) 
{
   echo "<font color='$ce'>Fehler </font></br>";
}
else
{
  echo "<font color='$cn'>Kein Fehler </font></br>";
}
```